# Magento 2 Customer Attribute in REST Order API

Tags: api, sales-order, rest-api, magento2.1.0

I have added a new custom attribute for order in `sales_order` table. It contains a value for the order.

I have added **extension_attributes.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
        <attribute code="custom_order_no" type="string">           
        </attribute>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

File **Company\Mymodule\Api\Data\MyModuleInterface.php**

```
namespace Company\Mymodule\Api\Data;

    interface MymoduleInterface extends \Magento\Framework\Api\CustomAttributesDataInterface
    {
        public function getCustomOrderNo();

        public function setCustomOrderNo($custom_order_no);

        public function getExtensionAttributes();

        public function setExtensionAttributes();
    }
```

If I retrieve the order with `/rest/V1/orders/4` REST api call, the custom attribute is not getting displayed